# Send data to HTML website from google sheets

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I have rows of data in google sheets and a HTML website which have text box to fill. Now I want to loop through the row in google sheets and pass it into the text box by HTML id, is it a possible thing to do? If so, please help me get some insights to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Possibly. What have you tried?

Comment: The starting point is for your web site to send a request to an Apps Script file, or send a request directly to the spreadsheet file using a url that gets the spreadsheet data as JSON.  You can't send a request from a spreadsheet to the users computer that has the site loaded in their browser.  You can embed an Apps Script Web App into the iframe of a site, and the Apps Script Web App can access your spreadsheet.  There are multiple ways to interact.  You could make an AJAX request from the site to an Apps Script Web App.  You could use server code from your site to an Apps Script Web App.

Comment: Does your site have access to server code?  If so, can your site's server code make an HTTPS GET or POST request?  Or, you can use client side code to make an AJAX request.  Or, you can embed an Apps Script Web App into your site.  Or you could use the Sheets API with an SDK.  Those are all possibilities.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer. Do you have some pseudo code for this type of connection? I am very appreciate.